# Road snapping in R - snapPointsToLine / Projection Problem

Tags: coordinate-system, r, road, snapping, maptools

**1. Introduction** (you may skip this if you like)

In order to implement a road snapping feature in R for recorded positioning data, I first searched the internet for possible solutions to the problem:

While it seems this can be solved with [fuzzyMM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyMM/index.html) (using fuzzy logic), the project using that approach is unfortunately not active any more and, thus, the [documentation](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/fuzzyMM/) does not include the kind of information that would be required to get started with the package itself.

Another solution could be using online geospatial APIs, e.g. [Google's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap). However, the current database already includes way more datasets than what's included in the free package.

At last, I found `maptool`'s function [`snapPointsToLines`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/maptools/docs/snapPointsToLines) (short introduction about how the function works can be found [here](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/296-snapping-points-to-lines-in-r)) and attempted to snap a couple of coordinates to lines provided by a shapefile.

Note: Because the GPS-data was recorded on cars mostly driving on major roads in Germany, I downloaded the respective shapefile (of Bavaria, i.e. Bayern) [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html) (`.shp.zip`).

---

**2. The specific problem**

Road snapping with `snapPointsToLines()` generates quite confusing values with this code. The following picture shows a list of recorded longitude / latitude values (see `pointsCoord`).

[image: A list of coordinates a.k.a pointsCoordinates]

```
roadsBavaria = readOGR("~/roads.shp", "roads")
pointsCoord  = getValuesFromPicture()

pointsSpatial          = SpatialPoints(pointsCoord)
pointsSpatialCorrected = snapPointsToLines(pointsSpatial, roadsBavaria)
```

Although this reduced test case sets the value `pointsSpatialCorrected` (see result at the end), it fails (code after that is not executed) with

```
Warning messages:
1: In RGEOSDistanceFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_distance") :
  Spatial object 1 is not projected; GEOS expects planar coordinates
2: In RGEOSDistanceFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_distance") :
  Spatial object 2 is not projected; GEOS expects planar coordinates
```

Note that this error occurs even when I apply the shapefile's projection on the `spatialPoints` manually via

```
pointsSpatial = SpatialPoints(pointsCoord, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**3. Additional information**

The resulting value of `spatialPointsCorrected` as displayed by `View()`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning message is quite clear here:

```
1: In RGEOSDistanceFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_distance") :
  Spatial object 1 is not projected; GEOS expects planar coordinates
```

It requires planar (Cartesian) coordinates, i.e. in meters, miles, etc. You however use polar reference system (WGS-1984).

You should re-project your SpatialPointDataFrame to a Cartesian projection of-your-choice (UTM is one option) and run the function again - it should fix this error. See this thread for additional info on re-projection to UTM: [converting-latitude-and-longitude-points-to-utm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639967/converting-latitude-and-longitude-points-to-utm)

*EDIT: Reprojecting to UTM zone = 32N, code and results*

See the following code and image. Re-projecting correctly fixes the problem.
The code using the data provided by the OP.

```
library(maptools) 
library(rgdal)
library(sp)


crs <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")     # UTM zone = 32 N
wgs84 <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")  # To create Points


bavariaUTM <- spTransform(readOGR(".", "roads"), crs) # get road data and project to UTM.

coords <- cbind("lon" = c(9.967067, 9.967218,
                          9.967507, 9.967502,
                          9.967490, 9.967453),
                "lat" = c(50.20421, 50.20419,
                          50.20411, 50.20410,
                          50.20410, 50.20410))

pts <- spTransform(SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = coords, 
                                          proj4string = wgs84, 
                                          data = data.frame("id" = 1:6)), crs) # create points and transform


pointsSpatialCorrected <- snapPointsToLines(pts, bavariaUTM)      # snap to the nearest road
```

Here are the original points coordinates in meters:

```
pts@coords
          lon     lat
[1,] 569012.3 5561784
[2,] 569023.1 5561782
[3,] 569043.8 5561773
[4,] 569043.5 5561772
[5,] 569042.6 5561772
[6,] 569040.0 5561772
```

and the coordinates of the snapped points:

```
pointsSpatialCorrected@coords
            X       Y
[1,] 569072.5 5561820
[2,] 569076.4 5561814
[3,] 569090.1 5561759
[4,] 569089.8 5561757
[5,] 569089.7 5561757
[6,] 569089.5 5561756
```

I also exported shp files of these two objects using: `writeOGR(pointsSpatialCorrected, dsn = ".", layer = "correctedPTS.shp", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")` and produced this image in QGIS (It can be plotted in R as well using `plot`, but the roads takes too much time).

[image: Colors stand for point ID]

Comment: Umm yesterday I didn't really take a look at the values returned, but as it turns out the values (now in UTM; converted back to WGS-84 and check via Bing / Google Maps) are even more inaccurate than what I had without reprojecting both shape file and points to UTM. I will try to update my question accordingly...

Comment: @Tacticus, see edits.

Comment: If I were able to upvote this futher, I'm absolutely certain I would do it.